# How to view all layers in timeline while animating 2D?

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d, timeline

I've been animating this project mostly on a laptop in the past.

I transferred it to my new PC and wanted to keep working on it but all the layers I had opened on the timeline are no longer there. Its probably a settings thing because I had to re download Blender~

[image]

Comment: Did you try to click on the triangle icon next to "Summary", to expand the layer list?

Comment: yes but nothing displayed.

Comment: To help troubleshooting, try to expand the outliner and see if there are layers reported, try selecting them, try adding a new layer with the + button in the GPencil Dopesheet, try to copy and paste the GP object into a new file, or upload here the file. https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I tried sending it through the stack exchange but it wont work. my file is 29.5mb and it says the most it can send is 30mb. Im not entirely sure why it isnt sending, it should be working but it just wont.

Comment: Start a new file, use the append function in the file menu to append the grease pencil object and see if it works. Uncheck the "invert search" button in the layer section (blue double arrow), Try type in the name of a layer. If nothing works, delete the heavier layers and upload this new file here.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! appending the grease pencil revealed all the layers automatically. Thank you so much, I couldve lost a lot of hard work!